LaTeX3 regex not working
I have a very strange bug and I guess I am not using LaTeX3 regexes as they are supposed to be used. My current document looks like this:
\documentclass{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_new:N{\myregex}
\regex_set:Nn{\myregex}{(.*)}
\NewDocumentCommand{\regextest}{m m m}{
    \regex_show:n{\myregex}
    \regex_match:nnTF{\myregex}{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\regextest{xxx}{T}{F}
\end{document}

But the output document shows :F (while the regex should match anything), and the log shows:
> Compiled regex {\myregex }:
+-branch
  char code 109 (m)
  char code 121 (y)
  char code 114 (r)
  char code 101 (e)
  char code 103 (g)
  char code 101 (e)
  char code 120 (x).
<recently read> }
                 
\regextest{xxx}{T}{F}

It seems that the regex correspond to the name of the regex itself (myregex here). Am I doing something wrong? How to make it work?

You need N not n type.

You need the :N version to refer to a command holding the regex, and also in all cases of N arguments do not use braces (it sometines works by accident but don't rely on it)
\documentclass{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_new:N\myregex
\regex_set:Nn\myregex{(.*)}
\NewDocumentCommand{\regextest}{m m m}{
    \regex_show:N\myregex
    \regex_match:NnTF\myregex{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\regextest{xxx}{T}{F}
\end{document}


shows
> Compiled regex variable \myregex:
+-branch
  ,-group begin
  | any token, repeated 0 or more times, greedy
  `-group end.
<recently read> }


it would be better to use \l_my_regex  rather than \myregex but that is not enforced.

Can I safely use braces for non-N arguments?

n arguments should always be used with braces, although as usual with tex if it's a single token you can omit them. for N consider \def you simply can't use \def {\foo} {abc}   that is a syntax error you have to use \def \foo {abc}  that is \cs_new:Nn  the first argument must not have braces.   @Vincent
